# how to scrape attribute in attibute with colly

Tags: html, go, web-scraping, html-parsing, go-colly

I try to scrape productId of a product but i can not. please help

html code

```
<span class="info">
 <button data-product="{"merchantName":"xxx","price":"11","productName":"car window","categoryName":"windows","brandName":"aa assosiations","productId":"which I want to scrape"}">
```

when I try

```
h.ChildAttr("span.info>button", "data-product")
```

result is `{"merchantName":"xxx","price":"11","productName":"car window","categoryName":"windows","brandName":"aa assosiations","productId":"which I want to scrape"}`

and when I try

```
h.ChildAttr("span.info>button", "productId")
```

there is no result.
how can I get this data with colly?

Comment: Never used go-colly before, but perhaps `h.ChildAttr("span.info>button", "data-product.productId")`?

Comment: thanks but no result again. i think colly not important. goquery or anything for parse html do it with same method, but I can not find from google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute value is a raw value, and in this case, it's in JSON format, so you will need to parse the JSON in order to correctly get the data.

For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector()

    c.OnHTML(`body`, func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        text := e.ChildAttr("span.info>button", "data-product")

        var result map[string]interface{}
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(text), &result)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        log.Println(result["productId"])
    })

    c.Visit("[some url]")
}
```

Output

```
2021/10/21 14:23:24 which I want to scrape
```

Comment: @Shinan I've updated to reflect your changes if that's ok

Comment: thanks for your answer and with your idea 
`var result map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &result)
fmt.Println(result["ProductId"])`